# php code to display data in pivot table format

Tags: php, mysql

My Database has data like below..

```
surveyorname       bookingdate       receiptno
  raj              20-03-2015         56   
  raj              20-03-2015         701 
  angel            21-03-2015         55    
  raj              22-03-2015         700
```

**Now  My Code display data like below format..**

```
surveyorname         20-03-2015
   raj                  2
  21-03-2015            --
   angel                1
  22-03-2015            --
   raj                  1
```

**I need to display Report format like below...**

```
 surveyorname    20-03-2015        21-03-2015        22-03-2015  
    raj             2                                    1
    angel                            1
```

My query getting data properly but only thing is I cannot understand how to display this in above format...

```
   <?php
$book = $database->getRows("SELECT surveyor_name as srv, bookingdate as bd, COUNT(DISTINCT receipt_no) as num  FROM receipt_entry  GROUP BY surveyor_name, bookingdate");
$days=array();
$line=array();
foreach ($book as $b) {
   $days[$d['bd']]=1;
   if (!is_array($line[$d['srv']])) {
      $line[$d['srv']]=array();
   }
   $line[$d['srv']][$d['bd']]=$d['num'];
}
print "<table><tr><th></th>\n";
foreach ($days as $d=>$n) {
      print "<th>$d</th>\n";
}
print "</tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $srv=>$l) {
    print "<tr><td>$srv</td>";
    foreach ($days as $d=>$n) {
        print "<td>" . $l[$d] . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
} 
print "</table>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
SELECT count(*) as TotalNum, surveyorname, bookingdate FROM your_table group by bookingdate,surveyorname;
```

Comment: I already told my query and code works properly....plz help me to display data as i show in above table format....plz.....i need to loop  bookingdate  in same td and based on this bookingdate need to display total...below this date...

Answer (score 0):

```
$book = $database->getRows("SELECT surveyor_name as srv
   , booking_date as bd
   , COUNT(*) as num 
   FROM receipt_entry 
   GROUP BY surveyor_name, booking_date 
   ORDER BY booking_date");

$days=array();
$line=array();
foreach ($book as $b) {
   $days[$d['bd']]=1;
   if (!is_array($line[$d['srv']])) {
      $line[$d['srv']]=array();
   }
   $line[$d['srv']][$d['bd']]=$d['num'];
}
print "<table><tr><th></th>\n";
foreach ($days as $d=>$n) {
      print "<th>$d</th>\n";
}
print "</tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $srv=>$l) {
    print "<tr><td>$srv</td>";
    foreach ($days as $d=>$n) {
        print "<td>" . $l[$d] . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
} 
print "</table>\n";
```

Comment: but sir your code will not display any data on webpage....i put your code as it is as i update on my post...

Comment: and also give warning on Undefined variable: d

Comment: Yes, there is a typo in there - the code is meant to show you how to solve the problem, if you want me to write a working a solution then we'll need to discuss rates.

Comment: ok tell me your rate sir...i ask bcoz i am try to learn php and not more knowledge....if you help me on this solution i will be thankful to you..